# How do I update an object in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a form in `reactjs`, that I am going to use to create user.  Here is the important part my code:

```
   var AddUser = React.createClass({
    mixins: [OverlayMixin],
    getInitialState: function() {
        this.state.user = {}
        return {
            isModalOpen: false
        };
    },
    addScout: function() {
       UserCreator.addUser({
         user: this.state.user
       })
    },
    ....
    updateUser: function(e) {
        this.state.user[e.currentTarget.id] = e.currentTarget.value;
    },
    ...
    render: function() {
        return ( < button onClick = { this.toggleModal} type = "button" className = "btn btn-success" >Add User < /button>
        );
    },
    renderOverlay: function() {
        if (!this.state.isModalOpen) {
            return <span></span>
        }
        return (
            < Modal title = "Add a User" onRequestHide = { this.handleToggle} >
                < div className = "modal-body" >
                    <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                            <input id="first_name" className="form-control" onBlur={this.updateUser}></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                            <input id="last_name" className="form-control" onBlur={this.updateUser}></input>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                < /div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                    <button onClick={this.addUser} className="btn btn-primary">Add</button >
                    <button onClick={this.toggleModal} className="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button >
                < /div>
            </Modal >
        );
    }
});
```

When the user opens the modal and inputs a first or last name, then the blur event triggers the `updateUser`.  When the `addUser` button is clicked then the `UserCreator.addUser` is called.

The problem is that I am not setting the state with `setState`.  What is the `reactjs` way to handle these inputs.  How do I create an object to push the inputs into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that I am not setting the state with setState. What is the reactjs way to handle these inputs. How do I create an object to push the inputs into?

The react way to handle it is with setState.

You can just do `this.setState({user:user})` and it'll update your view.

Or you can do something like this if you have a merge/defaults function.  It's not mutating the user object, it creates an updated version of it.

```
updateUser: function(e) {
    var update = {};
    update[e.currentTarget.id] = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState({user: merge({}, user, update)};
},
```

---

You shouldn't be using ids because you're making an assumption about every other component's implementation (ids must be unique!).  Instead of this, you could use a function which returns a change handler.

```
makeChangeHandler: function(property) {
    return function(event){
        // apply it to state; optionally replace this with the immutable example from above
        this.state.user[property] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({user: this.state.user});
    }.bind(this)
}

<input className="form-control" onBlur={this.makeChangeHandler('first_name')}></input>
```

---

You getInitialState function should look like this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        isModalOpen: false,
        user: {}
    };
},
```

---

Side note: read [Working with Forms](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).